# Launching shells in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Im trying to write a script which will be linked to my .fvwmrc and basically launches numerous shells and automatically ssh to a certain machine as a certain user.

For example:

I click on a button in my fvwm menu (e.g. goToChicago_AsPro) - this buttons runs the script.
The script launches four shells - with each shell automatically ssh'ing to a pre defined machine as a user "pro".

Now this is my problem:

When I ssh to these machines as user "pro" I need to enter a password. I do not mind this. Essentially what I want is to click "goToChicago_AsPro" and four shells pop up, each ssh'd to the correct machine as user "pro" and waiting for me to enter the "pro" user password.

Instead - what happens when I'm testing is.. the shell I run the script in will ask me for the pro password THEN launch one of the shells ssh'ing to the machine as pro THEN just basically do nothing more.

NOTE: ssh-keygen for passwordless ssh is NOT an option for me.

See part of my script below:

```
mapfile -t hosts < /tmp/ChicagoHosts
NUMBEROFHOSTS=${hosts[@]}

echo ${hosts[1]}
echo ${hosts[2]}
echo ${hosts[3]}
echo ${hosts[4]}

exec ssh ${hosts[1]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43+1922+0 -sl 10000
exec ssh ${hosts[2]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43-0+0 -sl 10000
exec ssh ${hosts[3]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43+1922+0 -sl 10000
exec ssh ${hosts[4]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43-0+0 -sl 10000
```

I also tried this but had no luck:

```
exec xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43+1922+0 -sl 10000 "`ssh ${hosts[1]} -l pro`"
```

When I add `set -vx` to my script this is what it spits out:

```
sts < /tmp/fixHosts.txt
+ mapfile -t hosts
NUMBEROFHOSTS=${hosts[@]}
+ NUMBEROFHOSTS='uk-chicago-000 uk-chicago-002 uk-chicago-003'

echo ${hosts[0]}
+ echo uk-chicago-000
uk-chicago-000
echo ${hosts[1]}
+ echo uk-chicago-002
uk-chicago-002
echo ${hosts[2]}
+ echo uk-chicago-003
uk-chicago-003
echo ${hosts[3]}
+ echo

echo ${hosts[4]}
+ echo

exec ssh ${hosts[1]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43+1922+0 -sl 10000
+ exec ssh uk-chicago-002 -l pro xterm -display bruce:0.0 -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43+1922+0 -sl 10000
pro@uk-chicago-000's password:
```

At which point the script just hangs. If I enter the password then a shell will be launched, and automatically ssh to uk-chicago-000 as pro. It won't do anything else.

Please help. Tried a number of things it just doesn't work.

Comment: That is because `exec` command replaces the shell with a given program. So other ssh commands won't execute. Could you please try without `exec`.

Comment: @Kadir ok I removed exec and reran the script - no change. Its still doing the same thing

Comment: As I try to do it on my test machine, after giving the password first xterm popup window appears then I press **Ctrl-C** and second prompt comes in. @nrs90

Comment: Ok but thats not what I need - Essentially what I need is four xterms to pop up, each ssh'd to the correct machine as user "pro" and waiting for me to enter the "pro" user password

Comment: As I understand that xterm popup windows would be opened in the local box then ssh commands get executed am I right? If then the logic is inappropriate and you have to fork xterms before the ssh connection. Like this: `xterm -ls -fn fixed -geometry 155x43+1922+0 -sl 10000 -e "ssh -l pro ${hosts[1]}" &` @nrs90

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use the `ssh-agent`.

I start X11 under the agent with

```
/usr/bin/ssh-agent startx -- -s 120 -v 2
```

Then in my `.xinitrc` (or equivalent X session startup file) that then starts fvwm I have

```
if test -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID"; then
  SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/local/bin/ssh-askpass ssh-add
fi
...
fvwm
```

That way you only have to enter your passphrase once.

It works by setting some environment variables that are passed to all forked processes, which then can contact the agent when authentication is required.

Next, as Kadir already pointed out, `exec` *replaces* a process. If an `exec` is successful, the script is gone and no more commands following the `exec` are run. I suggest you try running the four scripts in the background (note `&`):

```
ssh ${hosts[1]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY ... &
ssh ${hosts[2]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY ... &
ssh ${hosts[3]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY ... &
ssh ${hosts[4]} -l pro xterm -display $HOSTDISPLAY ... &
```